# How to find the maximum Eulerian sub-graph in an un-directed given graph?

Tags: graph, subgraph

Given the next graph:

[image: 1.png]

How do i find the maximum Eulerian sub-graph?

The correct answer should be this one (sub-graph with blue edges):

[image: 2.png]

is there any algorithm to archive this? at least for small graphs like this one.

Comment: Well, every vertex must have even degree, so I guess you could select the vertices with odd degree and start removing edges, but this is not a programming question.